# How Do I Find the Amount of Items in My ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am currently working on project euler 22, and the prompt asks you to read in over 5000 names from a file and sort them then give them values, though that is not what I am having trouble with. I read the names into an ArrayList, but now I want to see how many items are in my ArrayList. I tried printing out names.size(); but it just printed out zero. I'm assuming that this is because there's only one row? But I when I print out names.get(number); with number being any number I choose, it prints out the name that is supposed to be in that box. How do I see how many items are in my ArrayList? I know this doesn't have anything to do with project euler but just wanted to learn how to for future reference. I tried looking up online how to do it, but wasn't able to get it to work. Can someone tell me how and explain the code? Here is my code by the way:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class main{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String name;
    int row;
    int count=0;
    File filepath=new File("../names.txt");
    List<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        Scanner in=new Scanner(filepath);
        name=in.nextLine();
        while(in.hasNext()){
            names=Arrays.asList(name.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    System.out.println(names.size());
}
}
```

Comment: Whoa...Don't name your class `main` thats not good. You should read and follow common naming conventions [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)

Comment: Also, you should not just catch an exception and do nothing with it. How would you know if you had an error..you just ate it. You should at least do something like e.printStackTrace() or System.err.println(e.getMessage());

Comment: And, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));  is preferred.
than just Arrays.asList..  because this resturns static array.

Comment: What is the format of your input file? Give an example

Answer (score 2):

You need names.add in your loop rather than the assignment statement.

names.add(Arrays....)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple of issues, but the main one is that you are using a regular expression that is not matching the way you want. Assuming you have a text file with multiple names on a line, with possibly multiple lines, this would work and is much simpler:

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String name;
        int row;
        int count=0;
        File filepath=new File("names.txt");
        List<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();

        try{
            Scanner scan =new Scanner(filepath);
            String someNames = "";
            while(scan.hasNext()){
                someNames = scan.nextLine();
                List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList(someNames.split(" "));
                names.addAll(namesList);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(names.size());
        for(String aName: names){
            System.out.println(aName);
        }
    }
```

You can change the split value if necessary, but keep it simple. 
If the names are comma separated, just change the `split(" ")` to `split(",")`
Also, you were doing a `scanner.nextLine()` before entering the while loop, losing the first line in the file. Finally, notice the `names.addAll(namesList)`, which insures you store all the names found on a line.

Answer (score 0):

Since the list *names* is the result, you should add new names in next line to the result. I think the following code may work.

```
while(in.hasNext()){
    names.addAll(Arrays.asList(name.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
}
```